# Editor PrimeNG 5.2.4 with Jhipster 4.13.x ( Quill )

Tags: jhipster, primeng

To use the NgPrime Editor component devo install quill

```
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor
```

The problem that I do not know in which files to put the css and the scripts, since according to the documentation I put them in the file "angular-cli.json", it does not work.

I tried to put the css in vendor.scss

```
@import '~quill/dist/quill.core.css';
@import '~quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
```

But it does not work either. He paints it but partially, as if he lacked styles and functionality.

I do not know where I should locate the css and ts. And if I also have to execute a specific command.

Can somebody help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you imported primeng css and theme? Have you tried `@import '~quill/dist/quill.core.css';` syntax?

Comment: I have tried what you tell me, but it still does not work.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the script, I added it in the file : .angular-cli.json,                                                                      
        "scripts": [
            "~quill/dist/quill.js"   //./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js
        ]                                                                                                           I've tried two formats with that. I do not know if that is the correct one (Or as with the CSS, they go in another file) and also if I have I must execute a command to integrate it into the project.